# How to make bpy.app.debug a prop?

Tags: python, interface

To show mesh indices you need to go to the Python console, type in bpy.app.debug, and then in the Mesh Display panel in Edit mode you can find the Show Extra Indices checkbox.

I would like to have a button or a checkbox in the Edit mode panel that sets the bpy.app.debug flag to true, so that i don't need to go to the python console for that.

The flag exists. So all it needs should be a prop with the valid parameters. That's where i struggle. It doesn't allow bpy.app, and when i just type in app then i get a warning that 'Context' object has no attribute 'app'

```
layout.prop(app, "debug", text="Debug")
```

How can i add a prop here that accesses bpy.app.debug?

[image]

[image]

Comment: The API reference has the following to say for bpy.app: "This module contains application values that remain unchanged during runtime". So I'd assume you're not supposed to change it during runtime. It seems to be a flag that gets set via command line parameters when starting blender.

Comment: Ah i see. So officially not changeable at runtime at all. And so it's mission impossible. But what i don't understand, the Python console can in fact change it at runtime. Confusing.

Comment: Yes, that is weird. But I think the whole Python API is very weird compared to other APIs...

Comment: Thinking about this, you might be able to fool blender into allowing access to bpy.app if you set up a startup script and define a function there that lets you change the bpy.app.debug flag, and then attach a reference to that function to some globally accessible item so that you can get at the reference and call the function from your script.

Comment: Hm. I already tried a own function. But it throws a not accessible error then. So it seems that this door is also closed. Well, it was worth a try. Thanks for the ideas :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Dummy property to update `bpy.app.debug` via UI**

[image]

Script below uses a dummy boolean property on the window manager, with an update method to set `bpy.app.debug` to same.  Button is prepended to the 3D view header.

```
import bpy
from bpy.props import BoolProperty

def toggle_debug(self, context):
    bpy.app.debug = self.toggle_debug
    print("bpy.app.debug = ", self.toggle_debug)
    return None

bpy.types.WindowManager.toggle_debug = \
        BoolProperty(update=toggle_debug)

# function display the button
def display_toggle(self, context):
    layout = self.layout
    wm = context.window_manager
    layout.prop(wm, "toggle_debug", text="DEBUG", toggle=True)

# prepend to 3d view header
bpy.types.VIEW3D_HT_header.prepend(display_toggle)
```

To add properties to, or display properties in the UI,  the object must be an [ID](https://docs.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_current/bpy.types.ID.html#bpy.types.ID) type.  Below is a simple test in python console to see if an object is an instance of an [ID](https://docs.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_current/bpy.types.ID.html#bpy.types.ID) type.

```
>>> isinstance(C.window_manager, bpy.types.ID)
True

>>> isinstance(bpy.app, bpy.types.ID)
False
```

see that `bpy.app` is not, hence the error trying to use `layout.prop(bpy.app, "debug")`

Also the error in your posted image is because `app` was not defined, assumed you meant `bpy.app`.

Comment: With bpy.app i got another error. But you never stop learning. Thanks :)

Comment: Yes as mentioned, `bpy.app`  is not an `ID` type, or as the error would say an 'AnyType` type.   Cheers.